# Validação antes de enviar um formulário

Tags: php, html

imagine o seguinte cenário:
em um formulario só será habilitado o botao enviar se a soma solicitada no input estiver correta.

Problemas que estou tendo:

- Ao recarregar a pagina 'caso tenha digitado o valor errado em um teste anterior' não limpa a mensagem informando que o valor esta errado.
- Quando coloco o valor correto habilita o botão enviar, porem seria mais correto já executar o envio do formulário.

```php
<?php


$valor = '25';
$disbled='disabled';
$info='';
if(isset($_POST['formvalor'])){ 
    $resposta=$_POST['resposta'];
    
    if($resposta != $valor){
        
        $info='O valor esta errado!';
        
    }else{
        
        $disbled='';
    }
    
}


?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>


    <form action="" method="post">

<?php 
    echo "Quanto é 10 + 15 ? ";
?>
    <input type="number" name="resposta" id="resposta">
        
    <input type="submit" name="formvalor" id="formvalor" disabled value="ok"><br>
    <br>
    
    </form>
<?php echo $info ?> 
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="formenvia" <?php echo $disbled; ?> value="enviar"><br>
    </form> 
    
    

    
<script> /* verifica se existe ao menos 1 caractere inserido no input para habilitar o botao "ok" */

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#resposta').on('input', function(){
    $('#formvalor').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length < 1);
  });
});
    
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Se eu entendi direito o que você está querendo, segue abaixo o código.

Quando a resposta for correta, ao clicar no botão 'OK' vai mostrar um alerta. Ao invés do alerta é só você enviar o formulário.

Eu também incluí uma limpeza da mensagem assim que o usuário começar a digitar novamente uma resposta. Fique a vontade para alterar como achar melhor.

```
<?php
$valor = '25';
$disbled = 'disabled';
$info = '';

if (isset($_POST['formvalor'])) {
    $resposta = $_POST['resposta'];

    if ($resposta != $valor) {
        $info = 'O valor esta errado!';
    } else {
        $disbled = '';
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sem título</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php
        echo "Quanto é 10 + 15 ? ";
        ?>
        <input type="number" name="resposta" id="resposta">
        <input type="submit" name="formvalor" id="formvalor" disabled value="ok"><br>
        <br>
    </form>
    <span class="info"><?php echo $info ?></span>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="formenvia" <?php echo $disbled; ?> value="enviar"><br>
    </form>
    <script>
        /* verifica se existe ao menos 1 caractere inserido no input para habilitar o botao "ok" */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#resposta').on('input', function() {
                $('#formvalor').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length < 1);   

                if ($('.info').text().length > 0) {
                    $('.info').text('');
                }
            });

            $('#formvalor').on('click', function() {
                if ($('#resposta').val() == <?=$valor?>) {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).